# How to show that Airy Function in Integral form obeys $y''=xy$?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals, airy-functions

I wanna show that having Airy function defined as:
$$ \mathrm {Ai} (x)={\dfrac {1}{\pi }}\int _{0}^{\infty }\cos \left({\dfrac {t^{3}}{3}}+xt\right)dt $$

Solves equation:
$$y''=xy.$$

Edit: After clearing out that $k^3$ is not $x^3$, which i have misread:
I am stuck at the integral:
$$  \int_0^\infty (k^2+x)\cos(kx+k^3) $$ which is clearly not converging but some how wiki says it right solution?

Comment: Did you try to differentiate the airy function ?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: Yeah i tried, and after putting all in one integral  've got something ugly, which i am not sure what do next.

Comment: Careful! There's a regularization issue at $t=\infty$:$$\operatorname{Ai}^{\prime\prime}(x)-x\operatorname{Ai}(x)=-\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^\infty(t^2+x)\cos(t^3/3+xt)dt=-\frac{1}{\pi}[\sin(t^3/3+xt)]_0^\infty.$$

Comment: @J.G. Can u expand or give futher reading?

Comment: You forget a $1/3$ in the cosine function...Then you have $\int \cos u \: du$ where $u=t^3/3+tx$

Comment: But still is not converging, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Hints:

1. Rewrite the [Airy function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Airy_function) as
   $$\begin{align} \mathrm {Ai} (x)~:=~& \int_{\mathbb{R}_+}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{\pi}  \cos \left({\frac{k^{3}}{3}}+ xk\right) 
   ~=~\ldots \cr
   ~=~&  \int_{\mathbb{R}}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi}  \exp \left({\frac {\mathrm{i}k^{3}}{3}}+\mathrm{i} xk\right)\cr
   ~=~&\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0^+} \int_{\mathbb{R}+\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi}  \exp \left({\frac {\mathrm{i}k^{3}}{3}}+\mathrm{i} xk\right)  .\end{align}\tag{1}$$
2. Therefore the [Airy differential equation (DE)](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/AiryDifferentialEquation.html) is satisfied:
   $$\begin{align} \mathrm {Ai}^{\prime\prime}(x)-x\mathrm {Ai} (x)
   ~\stackrel{(1)}{=}~&\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0^+} \int_{\mathbb{R}+\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi} (-k^2-x)\exp \left({\frac {\mathrm{i}k^{3}}{3}}+\mathrm{i} xk\right)\cr
   ~=~&\lim_{\epsilon\searrow 0^+} \int_{\mathbb{R}+\mathrm{i}\epsilon}\frac{\mathrm{d}k}{2\pi} \mathrm{i} \frac{d}{dk}\exp \left({\frac {\mathrm{i}k^{3}}{3}}+\mathrm{i} xk\right)\cr
   ~=~&\ldots ~=~0. \end{align}\tag{2}$$

Comment: Interesting way to bring the limit in